# readonly textarea to fit the content with angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

What is the easiest way to make a readonly textarea to fit it's content (no scrollbar)? I'm using angularjs and would want pure angualrjs, don't want to use jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
angular.module("app", [])
    .directive("autoHeight", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "EAC",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element[0].style.height = (element[0].scrollHeight < 30) ? 30 + "px" : element[0].scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    };
});
```

In your HTML:

```
<textarea auto-height> </textarea>
```

Comment: Did not work :(. Moreover for some reason the scrollHeight comes same for each textarea in that page and changes height for each textarea even though some of them only have 1 line of text.

Comment: My Bad..it actually worked. I had 2 directives one for changing height while typing and this one. I guess they were conflicting each other. Merged them together and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Putting everything together. This resizes the text area for readonly cases and while also typing.

```
angular.module("app", [])
.directive("autoHeight", function ($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, element) {
      if(element[0].scrollHeight < 30){
          element[0].style.height = 30;
      }else{
          element[0].style.height = (element[0].scrollHeight) + "px";
      }

      var resize = function() {
        return element[0].style.height = "" + element[0].scrollHeight + "px";
      };

      element.on("blur keyup change", resize);
      $timeout(resize, 0);
};});
```